# Android logcat error: "E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new und unexperienced to Android, trying to develop apps in Ubuntu 14.04 with Android Studio 1.4. I use two activities, and none of these activities, layout or the like uses a 'ClipTray'. However, in `logcat` I see the following entry:

```
E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
```

and google does not really help here (no luck to find anything even for just the phrase `hideClipTrayIfNeeded()`.

Although this is listed as an error, the app seems to work without problems! But I do not like to have unfixed errors!

I also see those lines randomly in my log file:

```
D/CliptrayUtils: setInputTypeforClipTray(): 0
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Addition: I just realized that this error probably only occurs when the app is running on the actual phone and I switch off the display. Could that be the cause of this error? Then it has nothing to do with the actual app and I will be happy...

Answer (score 7):

Ok, it's an old post but due to the fact that as I tested my application and I had exactly the same question, I would like to add that this issue is shown only in LG devices.
Testing the same app on a Nexus device this issue is not shown at all.
So I think, it is not an issue.